# How do I allow a single-item/sub-editor GWT Editor to remove itself from a ListEditor that contains it? e.g. on remove button clicked

Tags: gwt, indexoutofboundsexception, gwt-editors

While trying to use GWT's `ListEditor` system I was unable to find a working example where the UI of each item in the list had a delete/remove button.

The examples I found were all like [this one](https://github.com/branflake2267/GWT-Demos/blob/master/DemoGwtEditor/src/com/gonevertical/client/views/peopleedit/editor/todos/TodoListEditor.java)[1] and have an `EditorSource.create()` implementation creates the per-item `Editor` and appears to wire up a handler to remove the item from the underlying list via `listEditor.getList().remove(index)`.

However, the anonymous implementation of the deletion handler closes around the value of index at the time of the sub-editor's creation, this leads to `IndexOutOfBoundExceptions` or the wrong item being removed as each removal changes the index of all items that come after it.

I pulled my hair out for a while trying to see what I was missing in the examples that kept that from happening, but from what I could tell they really did all have that problem, so while the fix is fairly simple, I will still post it here so there is at least one example people can find that does item removal correctly.

[1] I think all the examples I found were all derived from the one I linked, although that one in particular had a little more logic in remove() and may have been doing something to avoid the problem like correcting the list order somehow, I haven't dug into the other code in that project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a minimal `ListEditor` example that corrects the problem found in other examples.

```
public abstract class FooEditor extends Composite implements Editor<Foo> {

    Widget root; // Instantiated explicitly or through uibinder

    // Implemented as one of uibinder+fields, fields, methods, or LeafValueEditor.set/getValue()

    public FooEditor() { 
        initWidget(root); 
    }

    // Used for brevity, could be any triggering mechanism, click handler, event handler, etc.
    abstract void onDeleteClicked(); 
}

public class FooListEditor extends Composite implements IsEditor<ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor>> {

    private class FooEditorSource extends EditorSource<FooEditor> {

        @Override 
        public FooEditor create(int index) {

            FooEditor subEditor = new FooEditor()
            {
                @Override
                public void onDeleteClicked()
                {
                    // =======================================================
                    //
                    // This fixes the problem present in other examples
                    // by determining the current index at the time of removal
                    //
                    // =======================================================
                    int currentIndex = listEditor.getEditors().indexOf(this);
                    listEditor.getList().remove(currentIndex);    
                }
            };

            setIndex(subEditor, index);

            return subEditor;
        }

        @Override 
        public void dispose(FooEditor subEditor) { 
            subEditor.removeFromParent(); 
        }

        @Override 
        public void setIndex(FooEditor subEditor, int index) {
            listPanel.insert(subEditor, index);
        }
    }

    FlowPanel listPanel; // Instantiated explicitly or through uibinder

    ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor> listEditor = ListEditor.of(new FooEditorSource());

    public FooListEditor() {
        initWidget(listPanel);
    }

    @Override 
    public ListEditor<Foo, FooEditor> asEditor() { 
        return listEditor; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for adding this. Definitely useful for the community :)